# Getting a type mismatch error

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting a run-time error 13 'Type Mismatch' on this chunk of code and I cannot figure out why.  I have not used the `Mid()` function before and that is the line that throws the error.  Beginner here, any and all help appreciated.

I am wanting that if line to check to see if the third character in a string equals 4.  If you know of a better way I am open to that as well.

```
For k = 2 To NRow
    If Mid(SummarySheet.Range("B2:B" & k), 3, 3) = 4 Then
        SummarySheet.Range("B" & k & ":D" & k).Cut
        SummarySheet.Range("R" & k & ":T" & k).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I do not think you can only paste the values when using Cut.  Its an all or nothing issue.

Comment: Also as to the Mid, you can only do one cell at a time not a range of cells.

Comment: `mid` of 3 characters but you only test for `4`? Edit: yea, as Scott says, you need `Range("B" & k)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is what you are trying to do:

You will need to iterate backwards through your data.

Mid only allows one cell at a time.  And the third criterion is the length so it should be 1.

You can set the values then remove the data from the set.

```
For k = Nrow To 2 Step -1
    If Mid(SummarySheet.Range("B" & k), 3, 1) = "4" Then
        SummarySheet.Range("R" & k & ":T" & k).Value = SummarySheet.Range("B" & k & ":D" & k).Value
        SummarySheet.Range("B" & k & ":D" & k).Delete xlshiftUp
    End If
Next
```

Now if you only want to clear the values and keep a blank row in the data then use this:

```
For k = Nrow To 2 Step -1
    If Mid(SummarySheet.Range("B" & k), 3, 1) = "4" Then
        SummarySheet.Range("R" & k & ":T" & k).Value = SummarySheet.Range("B" & k & ":D" & k).Value
        SummarySheet.Range("B" & k & ":D" & k).Clear
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I believe this is incorrect. Let's say Nrow = 100 and the if is true for the first time at k = 94. Then, the ranges B95:D100 and R94:T94 will be populated, while B2:D94 will be deleted.

Comment: It could work if you did not add the backwards iteration, but I think deleting with xlUp was not intended.

Comment: @SeanScott yes it should have been `xlshiftup`.  Fixed it, as to why iterate backwards.  If we are iterating forward and we reach row 6 which is true, then we copy and remove the line and the data shifts up. what was row 7 is now row 6 and gets skipped when the for loop iterates.

Comment: Though we cannot speculate on how the user is using this data, I believe your "data cleaning" approach would also benefit from changing the target indices, since we will end up with a bunch of blanks in the columns R:T. I will make an edit to your first solution.

Comment: @SeanScott I agree it will end up with a lot of blanks, that is what the OP was doing and I did not want to assume that they were not taking care of that with a sort later in the code.  But feel free to modify my code in your own answer that deals with this.

Comment: I assumed if you were going to organize B:D, you would want to do the same with R:T. No need for another answer, just a suggestion.

Comment: @SeanScott I feel as the OP only gave a small sliver of the code that I wanted to give the same output that their code would reproduce and not assume they want different.

Comment: I am under the impression that it was not the same output. The "cut" in his code does not shift up data.

Comment: @SeanScott that is why I included the second, then the OP could choose.  Like I said feel free to offer an alternative in your own answer.  I have already upvoted your answer so I would not be ale to do so again but if you did and I could I would.

Comment: I misunderstood the range of your clear, my mistake. I have upvoted yours as well.

Answer (score 2):

`Mid()` is used to get a substring of a single text value. Since you are trying this on an array, it will not work. I'm not completely sure this is what you want, but this should not throw an error:

```
If Mid(SummarySheet.Range("B" & k).Value, 3, 1) = "4" Then
```

Notice the reference is for a single cell, and the "4" is quoted to show that it's a string. I changed your last argument to 1 because you are looking for a single character.